# Shopify Timber Development Workflow

Tags: sass, shopify, timber

Working with Timber for a new shopify theme from scratch. Typically working with sass in the past i would use node-sass to compile locally. this obviously doesn't work as the timber.scss.liquid file has shopify assets in it. However using theme kit I don't get any feedback for any sass errors.

What's the best way to get feedback from theme-kit / shopify regarding sass compilation errors while developing? Or do we not edit the timber.scss.liquid file at all and write stand alone scss files?

Comment: Is this a client request or a personal one? I'm asking since timber is no longer supported/updated. You should try using Slate instead. I doubt that Shopify will help you with this, since they don't support it any longer.

Comment: Personal, just getting into theme dev. tried slate first but it was buggy as hell - not sure if that was just a product of developing on ubuntu or not tho. Might give it another shot

Answer (score 0):

as per @drip answer. I switched back to slate. I first tried it when it first released 1.0 so it was buggy, but now it's usable. Nice little tool.